# How to match String in foreach loop with preg_split in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have data with 2 parts with this separator `|`

```
$data = 'hello | Hello there
price | Lets talk about our support.
how are you ?| Im fine ';
```

---

And my static word is `$word= 'price'`

**My code**

```
 $msg = array_filter(array_map('trim', explode("\n", $data)));
 foreach ($msg as $singleLine) {
            $partition = preg_split("/[|]+/", trim($singleLine), '2');
            $part1 = strtolower($partition[0]);

            }
```

---

How can I match the data? I need the result to be like this: `Let's talk about our support`

Comment: You may want to include PHP in the title so that prospective helpers will know what language you are talking about right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a single regex approach:

```
'~^\h*price\h*\|\h*\K.*\S~m'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GHuzCW/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a line (due to `m` modifier)
- `\h*` - 0+ horizontal whitespace
- `price` - your static word
- `\h*\|\h*` - `|` enclosed with 0+ horizontal whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far
- `.*\S` - 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, up to the last non-whitespace char on the line (including it).

[PHP code](https://3v4l.org/64J1K):

```
if (preg_match('~^\h*' . preg_quote($word, '~') . '\h*\|\h*\K.*\S~m', $data, $match)) {
    echo $match[0];
}
```

Comment: Thanks . for single word this is a on of the best ans , but there was a problem if i want last result then its not working  ```how are you ?| Im fine```

Comment: @RubelKhan It is working for it as well. See [the PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/kqbBF).

Answer (score 0):

Wiktor's answer seems good, but you might want to turn your data into a `key -> value` array.

If that is the case, you may do this:

```
$avp = [];
if (preg_match_all('/^ \h* (?<key>[^|]+?) \h* \| \h* (?<value>[^$]+?) \h* $/mx', $data, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
  foreach ($matches as [, $key, $value]) {
    $avp[$key] = $value;
  }
}

$word = 'price';
echo $avp[$word];  // Lets talk about our support.
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/uMBAg**